# I am designing a contact form and cannot get it to align correctly

Tags: css

I am attempting to make a contact form, but my text "email" will not go down to the line it is supposed to be in.

I also have no idea how to align the entire contact form closer to the right side of the page, you can see my poor attempt with the align left tags.

```
<div class="content">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <div id="contact-align">
            <div id="envelope">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Your Name</label>
                <input name="name" placeholder="Paul Farley" type="text"/>
            <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" placeholder="yourname@gmail.com" type="text"/>
            <label>Contact Number</label>
                <input name="contact" placeholder="123456789" type="text"/>
            <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea cols="15" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5">
                    </textarea>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
        </form>
        </div>
```

CSS code :

```
div#envelope {
    width: 52%;
    margin: 7px 10% 7px 5%;
    padding:5px 0;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
form {
    width:70%;
    margin:3% 15%;
}
input[type=text] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:75%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
}
input[type=submit] {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
    background-color: #4180C5;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#submit:hover {
    background-color: #34669E;
}
textarea {
    width:100%;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border:1px solid #7ac9b7;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    resize:none;
}
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: #4697e4;
}
label {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
#contact-align {
    left:60%;
}
```

Comment: just restrict the envelope to `width: 350px;` instead of `width: 52%;` and it will solve all your problems

Comment: It will, but that is hardly a solution if Paul doesn't want the width to be 350px ... instead you could add width: 100% to your label which will maintain the flexibility of your form while getting your labels where I'm assuming you want them.

Comment: I changed the width to 350px and that resolved the location of the word "email". I did it this way because I wasn't quite sure what Simon Mason meant by changing it to 100% because that made it look huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When putting forms together I usually wrap the inputs with the labels. It helps things flow together a little more easily.

As far as alignment, I removed `#contact-align` because it wasn't really needed and I removed `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` from the labels and changed the margin on `#envelope` to `7px 60%`.

```css
#envelope {
  width: 52%;
  margin: 7px 60%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
form {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 3% 15%;
}
input[type=text] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
}
input[type=submit] {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  background-color: #4180C5;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#submit:hover {
  background-color: #34669E;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  resize: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: #4697e4;
}
label {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>

  <div id="envelope">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>Your Name
        <input name="name" placeholder="Paul Farley" type="text" />
      </label>
      <label>Email
        <input name="email" placeholder="yourname@gmail.com" type="text" />
      </label>
      <label>Contact Number
        <input name="contact" placeholder="123456789" type="text" />
      </label>
      <label>Message
        <textarea cols="15" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </label>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks apual. I made the changes as you suggested, but this only centered the form. Ideally I want the form to start at about 60% of the page.